# GetUpdateSQL not giving a valid query for adodb-PHP 5.22.6

Tags: php, adodb-php

So here is my setup: running apache with PHP 8.2.10 with a MariaDB 10.11.4 and trying to upgrade from adodb 5.20.14 to 5.22.6 (the newest) since the old adodb is not fully compatible with the newest PHP:

So for both versions of adodb the used php code is as follows (simplified):

```
$db = \DB\openDB();
$record = $db->execute("SELECT * FROM `Room` WHERE `ID` = ?", array(186));
$newrecord = array('Name' => "newname"); 
$updateSQL = $db->GetUpdateSQL($record, $newrecord);
```

`$record` in both cases does not give an error but there is a slight difference in the output, the ADORecordSet_mysqli Object has a key called `sql` which is different. Old/new adodb:

```
[sql] => SELECT * FROM `Room` WHERE `ID` = 186
[sql] => SELECT * FROM `Room` WHERE `ID` = ?
```

i.e. the newer adodb object does seems to contain the 'raw' sql, wheras the old adodb processes the bind variables. I think this might influence the `GetUpdateSQL` command into giving the wrong sql (old/new):

```
UPDATE `Room` SET NAME='newname' WHERE `ID` = 186
UPDATE `Room` SET NAME='newname' WHERE `ID` = ?
```

If i change the `execute` command to not have bound variables by hardcoding:

```
$rs = $db->execute("SELECT * FROM `Room` WHERE `ID` = 186");
```

Then `GetUpdateSQL` gives the same (correct) updating sql:

```
UPDATE `Room` SET NAME='newname' WHERE `ID` = 186
```

Is this some new bug in adodb, or is there some functionality deprecated? Even with `$db->debug = true` activated it doesn't spawn any errors, and also no php/apache errors are logged for both versions.

Here is the raw adodb object for the execute command:
Old adodb:

```
ADORecordSet_mysqli Object
(
    [databaseType] => mysqli
    [canSeek] => 1
    [dataProvider] => native
    [fields] => Array
        (
            [0] => 186
            [ID] => 186
            [1] => Agora XXXX  XXX  XXX
            [Name] => Agora XXXX  XXX  XXX
            [2] => 52.24337
            [Latitude] => 52.24337
            [3] => 6.853513
            [Longitude] => 6.853513
            [4] => Building Vrijhof - Theatre Agora
            [Description] => Building Vrijhof - Theatre Agora
            [5] => 
            [PhoneNumber] => 
            [6] => 26
            [RoomTypeID] => 26
        )

    [blobSize] => 100
    [sql] => SELECT * FROM `Room` WHERE `ID` = 186
    [EOF] => 
    [emptyTimeStamp] => &nbsp;
    [emptyDate] => &nbsp;
    [debug] => 
    [timeCreated] => 0
    [bind] => 
    [fetchMode] => 3
    [connection] => ADODB_mysqli Object
        (
            [databaseType] => mysqli
            [dataProvider] => mysql
            [hasInsertID] => 1
            [hasAffectedRows] => 1
            [metaTablesSQL] => SELECT
            TABLE_NAME,
            CASE WHEN TABLE_TYPE = 'VIEW' THEN 'V' ELSE 'T' END
        FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
        WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA=
            [metaColumnsSQL] => SHOW COLUMNS FROM `%s`
            [fmtTimeStamp] => 'Y-m-d H:i:s'
            [hasLimit] => 1
            [hasMoveFirst] => 1
            [hasGenID] => 1
            [isoDates] => 1
            [sysDate] => CURDATE()
            [sysTimeStamp] => NOW()
            [hasTransactions] => 1
            [forceNewConnect] => 
            [poorAffectedRows] => 1
            [clientFlags] => 0
            [substr] => substring
            [port] => 3306
            [socket] => 
            [_bindInputArray] => 
            [nameQuote] => `
            [optionFlags] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => 5
                            [1] => 0
                        )

                )

            [arrayClass] => ADORecordSet_array_mysqli
            [multiQuery] => 
            [_genIDSQL] => update %s set id=LAST_INSERT_ID(id+1);
            [_genSeqSQL] => create table if not exists %s (id int not null)
            [_genSeqCountSQL] => select count(*) from %s
            [_genSeq2SQL] => insert into %s values (%s)
            [_dropSeqSQL] => drop table if exists %s
            [database] => PoFDB
            [host] => [redacted]
            [user] => pofDBuser
            [password] => not stored
            [debug] => 1
            [maxblobsize] => 262144
            [concat_operator] => +
            [length] => length
            [random] => rand()
            [upperCase] => upper
            [fmtDate] => 'Y-m-d'
            [true] => 1
            [false] => 0
            [replaceQuote] => \'
            [charSet] => 
            [metaDatabasesSQL] => 
            [uniqueOrderBy] => 
            [emptyDate] => &nbsp;
            [emptyTimeStamp] => &nbsp;
            [lastInsID] => 
            [hasTop] => 
            [readOnly] => 
            [genID] => 0
            [raiseErrorFn] => 
            [cacheSecs] => 3600
            [memCache] => 
            [memCacheHost] => 
            [memCachePort] => 11211
            [memCacheCompress] => 
            [sysUTimeStamp] => 
            [noNullStrings] => 
            [numCacheHits] => 0
            [numCacheMisses] => 0
            [pageExecuteCountRows] => 1
            [uniqueSort] => 
            [leftOuter] => 
            [rightOuter] => 
            [ansiOuter] => 
            [autoRollback] => 
            [fnExecute] => 
            [fnCacheExecute] => 
            [blobEncodeType] => 
            [rsPrefix] => ADORecordSet_
            [autoCommit] => 1
            [transOff] => 0
            [transCnt] => 0
            [fetchMode] => 
            [null2null] => null
            [bulkBind] => 
            [_oldRaiseFn] => 
            [_transOK] => 
            [_connectionID] => mysqli Object
                (
                    [affected_rows] => 1
                    [client_info] => mysqlnd 8.0.30
                    [client_version] => 80030
                    [connect_errno] => 0
                    [connect_error] => 
                    [errno] => 0
                    [error] => 
                    [error_list] => Array
                        (
                        )

                    [field_count] => 7
                    [host_info] => [redacted]
                    [info] => 
                    [insert_id] => 0
                    [server_info] => 10.11.4-MariaDB-1:10.11.4+maria~ubu2204
                    [server_version] => 101104
                    [sqlstate] => 00000
                    [protocol_version] => 10
                    [thread_id] => 459819
                    [warning_count] => 0
                )

            [_errorMsg] => 
            [_errorCode] => 
            [_queryID] => mysqli_result Object
                (
                    [current_field] => 0
                    [field_count] => 7
                    [lengths] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => 3
                            [1] => 20
                            [2] => 8
                            [3] => 8
                            [4] => 32
                            [5] => 0
                            [6] => 2
                        )

                    [num_rows] => 1
                    [type] => 0
                )

            [_isPersistentConnection] => 
            [_evalAll] => 
            [_affected] => 
            [_logsql] => 
            [_transmode] => 
            [connectionParameters:protected] => Array
                (
                )

            [databaseName] => PoFDB
        )

    [_numOfRows] => 1
    [_numOfFields] => 7
    [_queryID] => mysqli_result Object
        (
            [current_field] => 0
            [field_count] => 7
            [lengths] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 3
                    [1] => 20
                    [2] => 8
                    [3] => 8
                    [4] => 32
                    [5] => 0
                    [6] => 2
                )

            [num_rows] => 1
            [type] => 0
        )

    [_currentRow] => 0
    [_closed] => 
    [_inited] => 1
    [_obj] => 
    [_names] => 
    [_currentPage] => -1
    [_atFirstPage] => 
    [_atLastPage] => 
    [_lastPageNo] => -1
    [_maxRecordCount] => 0
    [datetime] => 
    [adodbFetchMode] => 0
)
```

New adodb:

```
ADORecordSet_mysqli Object
(
    [databaseType] => mysqli
    [canSeek] => 1
    [connection] => ADODB_mysqli Object
        (
            [databaseType] => mysqli
            [dataProvider] => mysql
            [hasInsertID] => 1
            [hasAffectedRows] => 1
            [metaTablesSQL] => SELECT
            TABLE_NAME,
            CASE WHEN TABLE_TYPE = 'VIEW' THEN 'V' ELSE 'T' END
        FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
        WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA=
            [metaColumnsSQL] => SHOW COLUMNS FROM `%s`
            [fmtTimeStamp] => 'Y-m-d H:i:s'
            [hasLimit] => 1
            [hasMoveFirst] => 1
            [hasGenID] => 1
            [isoDates] => 1
            [sysDate] => CURDATE()
            [sysTimeStamp] => NOW()
            [hasTransactions] => 1
            [forceNewConnect] => 
            [poorAffectedRows] => 1
            [clientFlags] => 0
            [substr] => substring
            [port] => 3306
            [socket] => 
            [_bindInputArray] => 
            [nameQuote] => `
            [optionFlags] => Array
                (
                )

            [arrayClass] => ADORecordSet_array_mysqli
            [multiQuery] => 
            [ssl_key] => 
            [ssl_cert] => 
            [ssl_ca] => 
            [ssl_capath] => 
            [ssl_cipher] => 
            [_connectionID] => mysqli Object
                (
                    [affected_rows] => -1
                    [client_info] => mysqlnd 8.0.30
                    [client_version] => 80030
                    [connect_errno] => 0
                    [connect_error] => 
                    [errno] => 0
                    [error] => 
                    [error_list] => Array
                        (
                        )

                    [field_count] => 7
                    [host_info] => [redacted]
                    [info] => 
                    [insert_id] => 0
                    [server_info] => 10.11.4-MariaDB-1:10.11.4+maria~ubu2204
                    [server_version] => 101104
                    [sqlstate] => 00000
                    [protocol_version] => 10
                    [thread_id] => 463195
                    [warning_count] => 0
                )

            [usePreparedStatement:ADODB_mysqli:private] => 1
            [useLastInsertStatement:ADODB_mysqli:private] => 
            [usingBoundVariables:ADODB_mysqli:private] => 1
            [statementAffectedRows:ADODB_mysqli:private] => -1
            [isSelectStatement:ADODB_mysqli:private] => 1
            [_genIDSQL] => update %s set id=LAST_INSERT_ID(id+1);
            [_genSeqSQL] => create table if not exists %s (id int not null)
            [_genSeqCountSQL] => select count(*) from %s
            [_genSeq2SQL] => insert into %s values (%s)
            [_dropSeqSQL] => drop table if exists %s
            [database] => PoFDB
            [dsnType] => 
            [host] => [redacted]
            [user] => pofDBuser
            [password] => not stored
            [debug] => 1
            [maxblobsize] => 262144
            [concat_operator] => +
            [length] => length
            [random] => rand()
            [upperCase] => upper
            [fmtDate] => 'Y-m-d'
            [true] => 1
            [false] => 0
            [replaceQuote] => \'
            [leftBracket] => [
            [rightBracket] => ]
            [charSet] => 
            [metaDatabasesSQL] => 
            [identitySQL] => 
            [uniqueOrderBy] => 
            [emptyDate] => &nbsp;
            [emptyTimeStamp] => &nbsp;
            [lastInsID] => 
            [hasTop] => 
            [readOnly] => 
            [genID] => 0
            [raiseErrorFn] => 
            [cacheSecs] => 3600
            [memCache] => 
            [memCacheHost] => 
            [memCachePort] => 11211
            [memCacheCompress] => 
            [memCacheOptions] => Array
                (
                )

            [sysUTimeStamp] => 
            [noNullStrings] => 
            [numCacheHits] => 0
            [numCacheMisses] => 0
            [pageExecuteCountRows] => 1
            [uniqueSort] => 
            [leftOuter] => 
            [rightOuter] => 
            [ansiOuter] => 
            [autoRollback] => 
            [fnExecute] => 
            [fnCacheExecute] => 
            [blobEncodeType] => 
            [rsPrefix] => ADORecordSet_
            [autoCommit] => 1
            [transOff] => 0
            [transCnt] => 0
            [fetchMode] => 
            [null2null] => null
            [bulkBind] => 
            [connectStmt] => 
            [_oldRaiseFn] => 
            [_transOK] => 
            [_errorMsg] => 
            [_errorCode] => 0
            [_queryID] => mysqli_result Object
                (
                    [current_field] => 0
                    [field_count] => 7
                    [lengths] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => 0
                            [1] => 20
                            [2] => 0
                            [3] => 0
                            [4] => 32
                            [5] => 0
                            [6] => 0
                        )

                    [num_rows] => 1
                    [type] => 0
                )

            [_isPersistentConnection] => 
            [evalAll] => 
            [_affected] => 
            [_logsql] => 
            [_transmode] => 
            [connectionParameters:protected] => Array
                (
                )

            [customActualTypes] => Array
                (
                )

            [customMetaTypes] => Array
                (
                )

            [_metars] => 
            [locale] => 
        )

    [_queryID] => mysqli_result Object
        (
            [current_field] => 0
            [field_count] => 7
            [lengths] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 0
                    [1] => 20
                    [2] => 0
                    [3] => 0
                    [4] => 32
                    [5] => 0
                    [6] => 0
                )

            [num_rows] => 1
            [type] => 0
        )

    [dataProvider] => native
    [tableName] => 
    [fields] => Array
        (
            [0] => 186
            [ID] => 186
            [1] => Agora XXXX  XXX  XXX
            [Name] => Agora XXXX  XXX  XXX
            [2] => 52.24337
            [Latitude] => 52.24337
            [3] => 6.853513
            [Longitude] => 6.853513
            [4] => Building Vrijhof - Theatre Agora
            [Description] => Building Vrijhof - Theatre Agora
            [5] => 
            [PhoneNumber] => 
            [6] => 26
            [RoomTypeID] => 26
        )

    [blobSize] => 100
    [sql] => SELECT * FROM `Room` WHERE `ID` = ?
    [EOF] => 
    [emptyTimeStamp] => &nbsp;
    [emptyDate] => &nbsp;
    [debug] => 
    [timeCreated] => 0
    [bind] => 
    [fetchMode] => 3
    [_numOfRows] => 1
    [_numOfFields] => 7
    [_currentRow] => 0
    [_closed] => 
    [_inited] => 1
    [_obj] => 
    [_names] => 
    [rowsPerPage] => 
    [_currentPage] => -1
    [_atFirstPage] => 
    [_atLastPage] => 
    [_lastPageNo] => -1
    [_maxRecordCount] => 0
    [datetime] => 
    [customActualTypes] => 
    [customMetaTypes] => 
    [insertSig] => 
    [fieldObjectsCache:protected] => 
    [adodbFetchMode] => 0
)
```

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/255403/discussion-on-question-by-shuisman-getupdatesql-not-giving-a-valid-query-for-ado); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.